# Why does gcc use a relative address to the function pointer in assembly?

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, x86-64

**The C source:**

```
int sum(int a, int b) {    
    return a + b;    
}    

int main() {    
    int (*ptr_sum_1)(int,int) = sum;   // assign the address of the "sum" 
    int (*ptr_sum_2)(int,int) = sum;   // to the function pointer 
    int (*ptr_sum_3)(int,int) = sum;    

    int a = (*ptr_sum_1)(2,4);   // call the "sum" through the pointer 
    int b = sum(2,4);            // call the "sum" by usual way

    return 0;    
}
```

**The crucial part of the assembly code:**

```
lea rax, sum[rip]
mov QWORD PTR -24[rbp], rax
lea rax, sum[rip]
mov QWORD PTR -16[rbp], rax
lea rax, sum[rip]
mov QWORD PTR -8[rbp], rax
```

**The executing program instructions from GDB:**

```
   0x5fa <sum>: push   rbp
   0x5fb <sum+1>:   mov    rbp,rsp
   0x5fe <sum+4>:   mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4],edi
   0x601 <sum+7>:   mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x8],esi
   0x604 <sum+10>:  mov    edx,DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4]
   0x607 <sum+13>:  mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rbp-0x8]
   0x60a <sum+16>:  add    eax,edx
   0x60c <sum+18>:  pop    rbp
   0x60d <sum+19>:  ret    
   0x60e <main>:    push   rbp
   0x60f <main+1>:  mov    rbp,rsp
   0x612 <main+4>:  sub    rsp,0x20
   0x616 <main+8>:  lea    rax,[rip+0xffffffffffffffdd]        # 0x5fa <sum>
   0x61d <main+15>: mov    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x18],rax
   0x621 <main+19>: lea    rax,[rip+0xffffffffffffffd2]        # 0x5fa <sum>
   0x628 <main+26>: mov    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x10],rax
   0x62c <main+30>: lea    rax,[rip+0xffffffffffffffc7]        # 0x5fa <sum>
   0x633 <main+37>: mov    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x8],rax
   0x637 <main+41>: mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rbp-0x18]
   0x63b <main+45>: mov    esi,0x4
   0x640 <main+50>: mov    edi,0x2
   0x645 <main+55>: call   rax
   0x647 <main+57>: mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x20],eax
   0x64a <main+60>: mov    esi,0x4
   0x64f <main+65>: mov    edi,0x2
   0x654 <main+70>: call   0x5fa <sum>
   0x659 <main+75>: mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x1c],eax
   0x65c <main+78>: mov    eax,0x0
   0x661 <main+83>: leave  
   0x662 <main+84>: ret
```

I think that the `sum` label is just the starting address of the `sum` procedure - `0x5fa`, so I don't understand why `gcc` can't use it directly, but uses the calculation `sum[rip]` for this.

**Question:**

1. Why is `sum[rip]` used in the `lea rax, sum[rip]` instruction in assembly, instead of the simple `sum` label, e.g. `lea rax, sum`?
2. Will the `mov rax, 0x5fa` instruction do the same? Because we know the `sum` address after linking: the `call   0x5fa <sum>` instruction just uses it directly.

Comment: *The executing program instructions from GDB:* no, it's not executing yet.  You disassembled the executable from inside GDB, but the addresses are offsets from the image base (which isn't decided until the process starts).  *After* a `start` command, you'd see addresses like `0x5555555546aa` for `main`.  This address is *not* a link-time constant so it can't be used as a 32-bit immediate for `mov`.  (Also it doesn't fit in 32 bits, but static addresses in position-dependent executables *do*, on Linux.)

Comment: @PeterCordes You right, I just did `x /30i sum`, without `start`. And was wondered why all addresses so short, because usually them looks like `0x5555555545fa`, as you said :)

Comment: @PeterCordes "This address is not a link-time constant so it can't be used as a 32-bit immediate for mov." But why this instruction use it as constant: `0x654 <main+70>: call   0x5fa <sum>`?

Comment: near call/jmp use `rel32` encodings (https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/CALL.html), and the distance between two static addresses *is* a link-time constant.  (Or assemble-time, for locations from the same source file).  GDB's disassembler fills in the absolute address because that's more useful, but if you look a the hexdump you'll see the relative encoding.  Use `disas /r` in GDB, or use `objdump -d`.

Answer (score -1):

I believe that it might depend on your build of GCC, but on the Linux distributions that I use everything is set up to default to PIC builds. That's Position Independent Code. It's better for both shared libraries *and* executables, because the result can be mapped into memory anywhere without needing a fixup pass. It's better for security because ASLR can be applied.

With x86-64 there's no significant penalty for using PIC so why wouldn't it be used everywhere?

Comment: There is a penalty for PIC here: an extra `lea` instruction has to be used where a normal displacement would have sufficed otherwise.  And no, until recently, PIC was not used by default in amd64 binaries on UNIX.  This is a rather recent development known as PIE.  I have downvoted your answer because it is factually incorrect and does not capture the actual motivations for introducing PIE.

Comment: The penalty for position-independent code is small but non-zero.  The penalty for `gcc -fPIC` (to make shared-library safe code that respects symbol interposition) is significantly higher for access to non-`hidden` global variables and inability to inline functions.  Anyway, non-PIE executables don't use fixups, they have a fixed load address chosen by the linker, so `mov edi, imm32` can put a static address into a register.  And you can index an array with `[table + rcx*4]`.  See [32-bit absolute addresses no longer allowed in x86-64 Linux?](//stackoverflow.com/q/43367427)